# How do I stop PHP PDO from displaying automatic var_dumps?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, var-dump

I've got a unique error that I think most people would kill for, but I just want to turn it off.

The issue is that when using anything PDO, I get a var_dump of the PDOStatement. This happens on web pages, and CLI php scripts, and it is very annoying when you're looking for errors and every single line of SQL is showing up.

I don't have any lines that would output this, so I believe it's a configuration issue, but I can't find what I would need to do to fix it.

Does anyone have any idea about how to turn it off?

I also know it's similar to a var_dump because XDebug kicks in and displays it.

A screenshot of this can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlOEc.png

Comment: XDebug you say? Does your "unique error" maybe [look like this](http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace)?

Comment: You et sql query printed or some kind of error that contains query? If that is just query then yes you have some kind of echo/print_r/var_dump somewhere.

Comment: @Carsten - No, it is not an error anywhere in the code.

Comment: @MarkS - No, the SQL is fine and executing correctly. I do not have a var_dump anywhere in the code that is being executed, and I know this because on different machines this does not output the same errors.

Comment: It'd definitely be useful to see an example of this error - can you paste one or insert a screenshot? What are your `error_reporting` sessions - I'm wondering if you are seeing a very low level of reporting; e.g: `E_NOTICE` and so on.

Comment: Please show us a sample of what exactly that looks like.

Comment: It's not an error, but it displays as: [this](http://i.imgur.com/ftrYb42.png)

Comment: @Darragh - Nothing has changed the level of error reporting on the system. I did upgrade PDO before, because I was trying to install the MySQL versio of PDO, which failed horribly and I gave up on.

Comment: How do you "upgrade PDO"? That's not typically upgradable on its own.

Comment: Perhaps one of your machines is prepending a file in its .ini that the others are not, and that prepended file is turning on the debugging.

Comment: @deceze - I was trying to install the MySQL driver, which required a newer version than the one I had. I am now on pecl.php.net/PDO-1.0.3.

Comment: @AndyLester - I haven't modified any ini files since way before this issue occurred. It's now showing the SQL code everywhere, even when using a brand new ini.

Comment: @JBrace1990 To reiterate, you should post an example of this as context could help everyone get on the same page. Also, have you tried running your script with as the first line `ini_set('display_errors', false);` just to debug see if this output is suppressed or not?

Comment: PECL PDO is ancient, PDO is now part of core PHP. *This package is not maintained anymore and has been superseded. http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO* You cannot "upgrade" PDO independently of PHP itself. Maybe you have gotten yourself into a mess where you're running some ancient debug development version of PDO somehow?

Comment: @Darragh - Setting display errors to off does not help the issue. I'll also update the main post with a screenshot.

Comment: @deceze - I am not using the latest version of PHP, because we are using older versions on our dev and production machines. I am using:

PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Aug 31 2011 17:06:47) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with DBG v5.0.8, (C) 2000,2013, by Dmitri Dmitrienko
    with Xdebug v2.2.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans


PDO was installed through pecl and is version 1.0.3

Comment: PDO has been in the core since PHP 5.1, the latest PECL version is from 2006, 5 years older than your PHP version...

Comment: @deceze - Removing PDO and PDO_PGSQL from the machine results in the extension not being loaded.

Comment: I don't know how exactly you've screwed up your installation, but screwed up it probably is. I'd simply recompile PHP... :)

Comment: @deceze - removing and then installing PHP has no effect. It's persistent, and I need it to go away.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe it's a configuration issue

it is not.

> I don't have any lines that would output this,

You have.

> Does anyone have any idea about how to turn it off?

Just find the code that's printing this output.

Sincerely,

Comment: It is not code related, otherwise it would show up under other configurations. There is also command line code that hasn't been touched in months and is now outputting random lines of DB queries.

Answer (score 0):

From your queries it seems you use the [PostgreSQL Session Save Handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session-pgsql.php). It is possible that this extension writes the `var_dump`s, as

> [PostgreSQL session save handler is still under development. Refer to the README file in the source distribution for configuration details.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session-pgsql.configuration.php)
>
> ...
>
> [This extension is considered unmaintained and dead.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session-pgsql.installation.php)

However, you can write your [own save handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) for php - which can use PostgreSQL, if you want.

Comment: As mentioned above, it does not do it on any other sites/locations, so this can not be correct. 

We are using Zend sessions and stroing them in a PSQL database